# Is it possible in Django to call custom `QuerySet` method on reverse related objects lookup?

Tags: django, django-models

E.g. there are next `models` and custom `QuerySet`:

```
from django.db import models

class ActiveQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        '''returns only active objects'''
        '''supposing here would be a lot
           of more complicated code  
           that would be great to reuse
        '''
        return self.filter(is_active=True)   


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='products', related_query_name="product", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    objects = ActiveQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Could you tell me if there is a way to call the `active()` method like this:

```
category = Category.objects.first()
category.products.active()
```

instead of doing like this:

```
category.products.filter(is_active=True)
```

Or how to implement appropriately such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the custom queryset into the parent model, not the _set. You can change custom_products to any other word.

```
class ActiveQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        '''returns only active objects'''
        '''supposing here would be a lot
           of more complicated code  
           that would be great to reuse
        '''
        return self.products.filter(is_active=True)   

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    custom_products = ActiveQuerySet.as_manager()

category.custom_products.active()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. `category.custom_products.active()` - will results to queryset of all `active` Product instances - that's great. But i was also wondering if it's possible to write one 'multipurpose' `QuerySet` and to use it in all models e.g. ProductImage.. To use code that you suggested for, let's say, `ProductImage` model to get all active instances i guess i should write separate `ActiveProductImagesQuerySet` which should `return  self.product_images.filter(is_active=True)` and put it to Product model.

Comment: So i was wondering if there way to use more simple and intuitive call like `category.products.active()` and `product.product_images.active()` where `category`, `product` and other models that could have `active()` queryset method have the same `objects = ActiveQuerySet.as_manager()` definition. So if you have some more ideas - let me now.

Comment: в любом случае спасибо за ответ, приятно видеть земляков здесь ;)
But i'm still interested why can't i use my implementation of custom queryset method? Is it a reason that Django returns another queryset when calling `category.products` instead of mine `ActiveQuerySet`? And if yes, what exactly does Django return from `category.products`?

Comment: just entered Django shell - and ran `category.products.active()` - worked just fine.. i guess i just didn't reload shell after changes last time. Пора научиться писать тесты сначала. Ну зато немного пользы всем из этого вышло)